# Persist Object using Hibernate and Guice

Tags: hibernate, jpa, guice

I want to persist an object in my database, I'm using @Trasactional and @Inject from Guice to persist the data .... the hibernate configuration is declared in a file persistence.xml in ressources/meta-inf folder ....

```
import ca.model.jpa.user;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.persist.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.ws.rs.*;


@Path("/test")
public class TestService {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @GET
    @Transactional
    public String persistUser() {

        // User
        User user = new User();
        user.setPseudoname("Anonymous");
        user.setAge(20);

        entityManager.persist(user);

        return null;
    }
```

when I debug my code, the entityManager is always null ... In my understanding, the injection aim to initiate the entityManager. But it doesn't do so !

How can I correct My code ? thank you

---

Here the content of my file persistence.xml :

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>

            <!--PostgreSQL-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.metamodel.generation" value="disabled"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your EntityManager is not injected.

Did you implement a persistence module?

```
public class ExampleHibernateModule extends PrivateModule {

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        install(new JpaPersistModule("example-persistence-unit").properties(jpaProperties()));

        bind(ExampleAO.class).to(ExampleImpl.class);

        expose(ExampleDAO.class);

        Key<PersistFilter> key = Key.get(PersistFilter.class, ExamplePersistenceUnit.class);
        bind(key).to(PersistFilter.class);
        expose(key);
    }

    Properties jpaProperties() {

        Properties appProperties = PropertiesUtils.getApplicationProperties();
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.url", appProperties.get("hibernate.connection.url"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.username", appProperties.get("hibernate.connection.username"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.password", appProperties.get("hibernate.connection.password"));
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", appProperties.get("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", appProperties.get("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", appProperties.get("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use.query_cache", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");

        return properties;
    }
}
```

Another implementation example:
[Hibernate with JPA Annotations and Guice](http://www.benmccann.com/hibernate-with-jpa-annotations-and-guice/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share your persistence.xml? Because inside this file you can among other things declare the transaction type of your entity manager. Be sure you have listed that correctly.

And here's also a nice link: http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/types-of-entitymanagers-application-managed-entitymanager/

Comment: I updated my post to include persistence.xml, thanks

Comment: <persistence-unit name="manager1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
Change the type from RESOURCE_LOCAL to JTA, let's see what happen.